# what happens when validateInterval in the CookieAuthenticationOptions expires

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

What will happen when validateInterval timeout expires?
this is my authentication config

```cs
var cookieAuthOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Compte/Login"),
    CookieDomain = ".rdvdoc.fr",
    //si pas défini le cookie expire à la fin de la navigation, définit une durée de validité du cookie
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
    //pour étendre la validité du cokie à chaque reconnexion
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the computer logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(user, manager))
    }
};
```

what i want to know is: after the validateidentity timeout expires, GenerateUserIdentityAsync will be called, but where does the user object fed to it come from?

1. is it refetched from the database?
2. is it recreated from the cookie data?
3. another way?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manager is fetched from the owin context and the userId from the cookie. The user is then fetched from the manager.

```
...
TManager manager = OwinContextExtensions.GetUserManager<TManager>(context.OwinContext);
...
TKey userId = getUserIdCallback(context.Identity);
...
TUser user = await Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions.WithCurrentCulture<TUser>(manager.FindByIdAsync(userId));
```

Comment: thanks, so if i added custom claims in the GenerateUserIdentityAsync they will be lost? i ask because the information i put in the claim is availbale only on login.

Comment: If your custom claims are set in `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` they will persist. This method is what's called to regenerate the identity.

Comment: i have a very specific case where part of the users aren't stored on the database but on AD, i also need to reuse their password for some website functions, i resorted to storing the password in the passwordhash field when checking the password, and then create a claim from this value;
if the user is reconstructed, i can still find it back from ad, but i won't have the password anymore, will the claim still be valid or will it be reinitialised?

Comment: If you don't have the password anymore for reference then the claim will be invalid. However it's hard for me to say since `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` is a function defined by you. However this whole strategy of keeping the password around is strange to say the least. An ideal approach would have users stored in your app as well as AD but defer to AD when checking credentials. So essentially treating AD as a third party auth provider.